# Add to cart button appears/disappears immediately on hover

Tags: css, shopify

I'm having an issue with a particular collection on Shopify.

On these pages: http://www.cooldownjuice.com/collections/menu#cc and http://www.cooldownjuice.com/collections/juice-cleanses

On the products under, "Cooldown Cleanses," the add to cart on hover button appears and immediately disappears on hover.

This doesn't happen for any other items in the store.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you edit CSS for your website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because on hover, your `form` is sent down 165px.

```
.product_listing_main .product_img form {
    top: 165px;
}
```

This value is absolute and when the image is shorter, it goes under the image and overflows your div, so it's invisible. Changing to this should always center the button vertically on hover :

```
.product_listing_main .product_img form {
    top: calc(50% - 21px);
}
```

(21px is half the height of your button here)

Comment: wow never knew about the calc trick. definitely will be using this. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can add rule to CSS files try to edit CSS for this block:

```
.product_listing_main .product_img form {
   top: 50%;
}
```

Or if you can't edit CSS. Try to replace image of your product in this block. Height of new image should be at least 330px.

Comment: yes! this worked. thanks so much!